# 3Com 3CDSG8 Serial Console Input Not Working

Tags: hp, switch, 3com

I have a 3Com 3CDSG8 Office Connect Managed Gigabit Switch.

I am trying to restore factory defaults. I don't have original rj45 to db9 connector cable. So i am trying to make a new one to connect switch. First of all, the db9 diagram of documentation is below.

[image: Diagram from documentation]

And i have EA-100 rj45 to serial converter box and pin outs below,

[image: EA-100]

So i connected pins as described. But my problem is, i can see console screen but i can't send any input to device. I searched all google, the only thing i found is saying try to disable flow control. I allready disabled flow control as the documentation says. But all of my work i can't send any input.

Also i tried to connect as DB25. I used EA-101 DB25 adapter and for connecting DB9 i used DB25 to DB9 converter. Between connections i used RS-232 Check Tester adapter. The adapter RD lights on when data coming but TD is always lights on. I am adding lights picture.

[image: terminal window]
[image: connection tools]
Can anybody help me to input keys to console please.

Comment: First off, I gotta respect someone who makes his own RJ-45 to console cable.  Secondly, however, I need to point out that you can buy one you know is going to work online for less than 20 bucks... which needs to be your first step in troubleshooting this - buy a new, proper cable from the manufacturer, to rule out cabling issues as the source of your problem.

Comment: thank you for your advice, unfortunately i can't found original rj45 to db9 null modem cable for 3com in turkey. I tried other 3com switch console cables but in their documentation pin outs is different. I think this is a special cable. I did many other console cable like this, find pin outs and connect it as described. and all worked since now.